# My custom super+2 shortcut gets captured by windows since 23.10 (AZERTY keyboard)

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell, workspace-switcher

I like to switch workspaces with Super+1, Super+2, etc., so I disabled the default behaviour of these shortcuts and assigned them to workspace switching instead.
This setup used to work, until I updated to 23.10 a few days ago. Now the shortcut Super+2 gets captured by most windows as text input, while Super+1 or Super+3 do not get captured.

It should be noted that I am using an AZERTY keyboard layout. This means that the number row works a bit differently, in particular the second key of the number row is really "é" (and I need to use shift+é to input the number 2).
This seems highly relevant to my problem: the same issue happens with the Super+7 (which inputs "è"), and if I switch to a QWERTY layout, then the problem disappears.

Is there a way to fix this behaviour?
Thank you.